# Python pandas filter multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a bunch of headers, I understand we can use df.filter(regex = 'header') to get the specific column. What if I have more than one 'header' to filter, for example, my columns like below, I want to select any columns which contain '2018-08-19' and 'Frequency', regex seems doesn't work for filtering two words.

```
Index(['Frequency(Hz)', '2018-08-19 00:00:00Exhaust5BA-1A361nan',
       '2018-08-19 00:00:00Exhaust5BA-1A363nan',
       '2018-08-19 00:00:00Exhaust5BA-1A365nan',
       '2018-08-19 00:00:00Exhaust5BA-1A367nan',
       '2018-08-19 00:00:00Exhaust5BA-1A462nan',
       '2018-08-19 00:00:00Exhaust5BA-1A464nan',
       '2018-08-19 00:00:00Exhaust5BA-1A466nan', 'nannannannannan',
       'DateMachineSideGangheadSpindle Number',
       '12-01-2020MOD3Intake5BA-1A#351', '12-01-2020MOD3Intake5BA-1A#353 ',
       '12-01-2020MOD3Intake5BA-1A#355 ', '12-01-2020MOD3Intake5BA-1A#357 ',
       '12-01-2020MOD3Intake5BA-1A#452', '12-01-2020MOD3Intake5BA-1A#454',
       '12-01-2020MOD3Intake5BA-1A#456', '12-01-2020MOD3Intake5BA-1A#458',
       '12-01-2020MOD3Intake5BA-1B#351'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: `df.filter(regex=('Frequency|2018-08-19'))`

Comment: Thank you so much!